# Getting the items belonging to specified keywords and categories

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have a *keywords* and a *categories* table with an *ID* and a *name* col (I can't merge them into a single table!)

There's an *articles* table with ID, name, text.

And the many-to-many connection tables:

- *ckw* for keywords, columns: key_id, article_id
- *ccat* for categories, columns: cat_id, article_id

I can write a query to get those articles which belong to keywords ID 5 **AND** ID 7:

```
SELECT articles.name FROM articles
JOIN ckw ON (ckw.article_id = articles.id)
WHERE ckw.key_id IN (5, 7)
GROUP BY ckw.article_id
HAVING COUNT(ckw.key_id) = 2
```

But what if I want to get those articles which belong to keywords ID 5 **AND** ID 7, and also belong to category ID 12 **AND** ID 18? I can't figure the right query out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT articles.name
FROM articles
inner JOIN ckw ON ckw.article_id = articles.id
inner join ccat on ccat.article_id = articles.id
WHERE ckw.key_id IN (5, 7) 
and ccat.category_id in (12,18)
GROUP BY articles.article_id , articles.name 
HAVING COUNT(distinct ckw.key_id) = 2 
and count(distinct ccat.category_id) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks! But why do you group by articles.name?

Comment: Because, at least in proper implementations of SQL, you have to group by any non aggregated result in an aggregated query. If you write SQL this way, it will save you pain in the future. :)